# No sound in mplayer - A_OPUS codec

Tags: linux, audio, codec, mplayer

mplayer2 fails to play the sound of some `.mkv` files. I installed `vlc` and it is able to play with sound. mplayer2 output:

```
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team

Playing Invisible Gaps in the Wall-_qUKE6Y5z04.mkv.
[mkv] Track ID 1: video (V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC), -vid 0
[mkv] Unknown/unsupported audio codec ID 'A_OPUS' for track 2 or missing/faulty
[mkv] private codec data.
[mkv] Track ID 2: audio (A_OPUS), -aid 0, -alang eng
[mkv] Will play video track 1.
Detected file format: Matroska
Clip info:
 MAJOR_BRAND: dash
 MINOR_VERSION: 0
 COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
 CREATION_TIME: 2015-09-22 13:11:41
 ENCODER: Lavf56.1.0
Load subtitles in .
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_r600.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[ass] auto-open
Selected video codec: H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 [libavcodec]
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
VIDEO:  1920x1080  25.000 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kB/s)
VO: [xv] 1920x1080 => 1920x1080 Planar YV12 
V:   0.7   0/  0  9%  6%  0.0% 0 0 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

I tried using different codecs, such as `lavc`, `ffaac`, `pcm`... And `--audio-demuxer=mkv`, to no avail. I have `libopus0` installed. mplayer2 is from Debian stable repositories. I tried downloading the latest MPlayer instead of mplayer2 which isn't even supported anymore but it fails to compile.

Is there any way around this? I'm not much of a fan of vlc or mpv...

Comment: Interesting and no answer. I looked into this in the webm files which uses this codec. What is also interesting I have to use a video converter in order to get sounds from these files. I have a program that produces webm files, but there is no sound. Too bad nobody has found a solution. I think it's off topic, maybe you should move it to another thread?